# Texture bezier curves

Tags: texturing, bezier-curves

I'm pretty new to blender, and I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nn7mISvVzJk&t=) on how to make poly hair using bezier curves. The problem is, I want to make cc for the Sims 4, and I need to place a texture on [my mesh](https://66.media.tumblr.com/3396ee4a9ce5c2bb0c93ef921536b819/tumblr_pgv1u9j9W61xsklhgo1_1280.png). And I have no idea how to do it. I've tried to convert the bezier to mesh, then UV unwrapping, but it has [too many polys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5h854.jpg) and it gets [messy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G4UL.jpg). Could anyone help me out? (In case it's easier this way: I have Autodesk Maya 2018 aswell)

Comment: could you please show some screenshots?

Comment: I'm so dumb, sorry! I just uploaded some, if you need more I'll upload them right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have 2 questions: too many polys in your mesh and how to unwrap it.
Here is how I would do it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for you helpful and quick answer, it worked perfectly!